# Shall REST API error messages be internationalized?

Tags: rest, error-handling, internationalization

When designing the errors of a REST API seems to be a good practice to follow standard HTTP codes (4XX and 5XX) and to include a body (XML/JSON) with:

- brief message
- description
- code

My question is ... shall these messages be internationalized?

I tend to think that showing a message to the client is client side responsability, and those API errors should be considered as an agreement (format, and code field) between the client app and the API but shall not be considered by default as perfectly suited to be exposed to the client directly, so formatting the final message "Ooops ... something was wrong" shall be done at client side. In other case i can see API deployments because P.O. needs to change "Oops" to "Uups" and things like that, that seems totally like something related to the look and feel of the client app IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

You are right, most of the time you won't need to expose the REST exceptions to the client, since REST errors are too technical.

Still there are applications that will choose to let the user "drill into the technical error" - but even if this is the case I believe that the end user understands that now we are in the "techincal detials" area and won't expect translation of the message (+ translating technical messages simply won't sound good in other languages except English)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say if your whole API is internationalized and the client can choose the language through the `Accept-Language` header, then the API errors should be internationalized as well.

Comment: Not sure if i understand ... the communication format between client app and API is not internationalized since e.g. property values in JSON exchange messages shall not depend on user language ... in other case code in the client app must be specific for each language. So now stated this we face the point of the final user format for the messages. Do you agree that final format of messages are a client side responsability? ... if "yes" ok ... then if "no" i question who are the target for those error messages and i would say that the answer is: 1º Client app code, 2º Developers.

Comment: If this is the case then ... shall those internal error messages passing between client app and API be translated in order to potential developers understand it? ... i see this question much less critical and, personally, i would say no. I expect protocol and internal error messages to be in english.

Comment: There's no such rule that an API must use english. If your business requires that the API is internationalized, the correct way to do it is using the `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: I've never said that API must be in english. I choose english to define protocol and format between Client APP and API. I think the real important question is if you agree that final format of messages are a client side responsability or not.

Comment: That depends on your business, on your application. It's not something set in stone like that. If your business requires that the server is responsible for client messages, so be it. Either way, HTTP has support for it.