# DocuSign api error messsages language change

Tags: docusignapi

In case of an error in API call : is it possible to have DocuSIgn REST API respond in another language than english ?

I need to get the error messages in french.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Rest API Error messages should be language agnostic. These error messages are to be consumed by your client app and not exposed to Users.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242626/shall-rest-api-error-messages-be-internationalized) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the error message text is only available in English. Your app can use the error number to decide what to do and which French message should be shown to the user.

The error messages are listed on docs.docusign.com